# Sending an email to professor

Tags: grammar, phrases

I would like to write an email to my professor for getting an approval of my proposal:
I am writing to tell you that I already finished my proposal and looking for your approval?
Does is this sentence make sense? Or do you suggest ”another useful phrases instead of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> I am writing to tell you that I have finished my proposal and would like to submit it for your approval.

After that you can discuss other things if necessary, such as whether the prof would be receptive, if he or she has any recommendations for the submission, time constraints, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to state the obvious, that "I am writing"? Can't you just tell him or her that you've already completed your proposal and would like his/her approval?

Hope this helps, and best wishes for approval.